# Can't upload image to firebase with dropZone react

Tags: reactjs, firebase-storage, react-dropzone

Read and write are True on storage rules(firebase) but I get this error:

```
blob.ts:118 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'byteLength')
    at blob.ts:118:30
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FbsBlob.getBlob (blob.ts:117:19)
    at multipartUpload (requests.ts:357:24)
    at uploadBytes$1 (reference.ts:259:23)
    at uploadBytes (api.ts:122:10)
    at AvatarUpdate.tsx:20:10
    at index.js:708:7
    at index.js:759:9
```

This is my code:

```
import React, { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import "./AvatarUpdate.scss";
import { Image } from "semantic-ui-react";
import { noImage } from "@/assets";
import {useDropzone} from 'react-dropzone';
import { User, Storage} from "../../../api";
import { getStorage } from "firebase/storage";
import{ref, uploadBytes} from "firebase/storage";
const userController = new User();
const storageController = new Storage();
const storage = getStorage();
const uuid = userController.getMe()?.uid;
export const AvatarUpdate = () => {
    const [avatarUrl, setAvatarUrl] = useState(userController.getMe()?.photoURL || noImage)
    const onDrop = useCallback(async (acceptedFile: (Blob)[]) => {
         setAvatarUrl(URL.createObjectURL(acceptedFile[0]));
         const fileRef = ref(storage,`${"avatar"}/${userController.getMe()?.uid}`);
         uploadBytes(fileRef , acceptedFile[0]).then(() => {
         console.log('Uploaded a blob or file!');
         });
      }, []);
    const {getRootProps, getInputProps, isDragActive} = useDropzone({onDrop})
  return (
          <div className="avatar-update" {...getRootProps()}>
        <input {...getInputProps()} />
    <Image src={avatarUrl}/>
    </div>
  )
}
```

I tried looking for what acceptedFile[0] returned and discovered the path was set to "". So maybe when I selected an image there was no path and it couldn't send it to fire base?

Comment: In an example of drozone.js, the guy place his file in a console log and in the console his file did throw path, maybe the problem is because im using a Mac OS?